# mv -v , but only when something happens

Tags: centos, cron, mv, jails

For maintenance reasons, I have a cron job like `mv -vn folderA/* folderB`

However every time it is executed I got an email, even if nothing is moved,

can this be set to distinguish between cases?

(limited to jailed cron on Centos)

Comment: What's the message in the email when no work has been done?

Comment: What shell are you using in your `crontab` ("I haven't set one" is an acceptable answer, but only if it's true)

Comment: Please update your question with this information. Don't reply in the comments. Make your question flow - as if you'd  provided this information in the beginning

Comment: `cron` jobs email the (non-empty) `STDOUT`/`STDERR` stream. Wrap your command in a `bash` script, and you'll have full control of `STDOUT` (and `STDERR`).